# WPF, C#, Serial Port Communication

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I am using serial port communication, there is a `DataReceived` Event of Serial Port, in which if the header & footer of received data matches I am executing 2 complex & lengthy functions, here I have used circular buffer for data receive,

Out of the 2 functions first function updates a Graph (Area Chart) of 2058 bytes on Canvas & second functions does some complex calculations on 2058 bytes. I am receiving these 2058 bytes after every 3 seconds.

So my requirement is while I am filling data in buffer on the other side I need to execute these 2 functions on the data that is already in the buffer (as it is circular buffer it contains previously filled data).

I am little bit confused here, how to achieve this concurrency. I know some ways,

1. use 'Task'
2. use 'Threads'
3. use 'async & await'
4. use 'Task Parallel Library'
5. use 'Background Worker'
6. use  'Dispatcher.Invoke()'

Currently I am using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` which takes too much time for UI updates. So here time lag happens.

Please suggest me which approach will be more responsive.

Comment: Why not just take a copy of the buffer before you read in the new data and build your graph on that?

Comment: Yes, everything except 4 and 6.  You can run the "complex functions" on a thread, not the graph update.

Comment: You can do everything right in the `DataRecieved` event. It runs in new thread (*The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is received from the SerialPort object* - [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx)), which will be a perfect place to convert data for the graph, invoke graph and start complex processing. Consider to copy data first from circular buffer. If you can guarantee, what complex processing finishes before next data will arrive, then you can even use `static` buffer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed it successfully with timers and background worker synchronization.

The only important thing I noted is you need a good processor, at least 'core - i3'.

The solutions proposed by Mr.SKleanthous is also acceptable. Thanks.

And thanks Mr. Andreas Müller, yes I got your point.

Thank you so much everybody.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the size of work to be done, and since this is happening every three seconds, I believe that tasks and queueing work on the threadpool are your best solutions.

I would not suggesting spawning a new dedicated thread.

Depending on how long this process takes and your configuration, I think you may consider having a small number of permanent threads running in a loop and querying a queue of newly received data for processing (ie creating your own threadpool). This can be accomplished using ConcurrentQueue to post and receive data. Also you may benefit from considering [TPL.Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) which can help immensely in situations that require low latency and high performance in multithreaded environment. Regardless of the solution, you may benefit from investigating the [BufferBlock class from Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: +1 for dataflow. It's also easy to stick an `ActionBlock` at the end of the dataflow that runs on the UI thread (using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`).

Comment: I think `BufferBlock<T>` will be useful as you suggested because it can have multiple message input targets and single message receiving target which seems fitting in OP's case

Comment: I think it really depends on the situation. Obviously the best choice with regards to maintainability and support for future changes will be to use BufferBlock with ActionBlocks in the end or a dedicated thread pool to handle messages. However if the constraints are set in stone (one message every 3 seconds and processing will not take long), spawning tasks will be easier and may be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1-5 for complex work (as those are intended for this scenario). You could use 6 to inject your results into the graph, because the purpose of Dispatcher.Invoke is processing work in the UI-Thread and is required for the majority of controls.

I hope that helps.